# Delete Key Issue when using Code Behind

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

This isn't a code but it's an annoying enough problem to ask about.

Has anyone ran into an issue using the delete key while in code behind?
My delete button works when deleting text, but sometimes there is an issue when using it to remove empty lines and condense code. I will press the key, it removes 1 line, then the delete button won't delete another line until i lose focus of my current line and then
reenter my line.

To clarify i'll try to describe the situation using some pseudo code.

line1.focus => press delete removes empty line, press delete again does not remove next line

line1.blur, line1.focus => press delete works,

loop

It seems to be Visual Studio 2012 issue, because it doesn't seem the issue is happening with 2010 express

Comment: Works fine on my version... Are you aware of the difference between \r\n and \n?

Comment: I do now, I don't understand why you ask?

Comment: Would this be something with your user settings? You might have a keyboard shortcut badly mapped. Try going to Tool > Import and Export Settings > Reset All Settings.

Comment: Also, disable all plugins and extensions and try again. I use R# and a few others and sometimes they do odd stuff to my editor windows.